# Redis pubsub and scaling?

Tags: node.js, redis, scaling

For communication between the various services used pubsub. If you create multiple workers

> , they both accept data both to process them. What are some methods
>   that have worked in the same message, only one of the workers

.

PS Perhaps there are some layers, so-called message brokers

Comment: See [this](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush#pattern-reliable-queue) on how to implement such a thing on top of Redis, or use something like [Kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue). Alternatively, you can look at [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [nsq](http://nsq.io/) or other messaging platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Now I lean towards RabbitMQ or Kafka